# Proving that the the sequence $x_n = \frac{n^{100}}{2^n}$ converges using only elementary methods

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I realise that there are already questions on the site about this sequence or related sequences, but I'm looking for a completely elementary method that doesn't use:

- L'Hopital's Rule
- Tests like the comparison test or ratio test
- Logarithms
- Statements like "exponentials grow faster than polynomials"

I'm trying to show that the sequence $$x_n = \frac{n^{100}}{2^n}$$ converges as $n \to \infty$, where $n$ is a positive integer. I haven't been able to find a way to do this directly using the epsilon definition for convergence. Is there a completely elementary way to show that this converges (not necessarily needing to show what it converges to) without using any of the things mentioned above?

Comment: I don't think there is a proof without using mathematics, or brains.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I completely agree! I really do not at all understand people's obsession with "solve ___ without using ___", especially when it comes to limits without using L'Hospitals rule. The whole reason why these more advanced and powerful techniques exist is so that we **don't** have to use cumbersome $\epsilon, \delta$ methods.

Comment: @K.defaoite In that case, then what are your thoughts on students being asked to do exercises without using results that they haven't proved yet?

Comment: In that case, you'd better add that motivation to your question, together with a list of results those students *have* proved, so far. Excluding logarithms while reasoning about limits makes that quite a bit... erm... dubious, though. I mean, logarithms were introduced not later than 1614, while the concept of "limit" seems to be newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most elementary we can get. Look at the ratio between two consecutive terms:
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{100}/2^{n+1}}{n^{100}/2^n}\\
=\frac{(n+1)^{100}}{2n^{100}}\\
=\frac12\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{100}
$$
Now note that from some point on, $1+\frac1n<\sqrt[100]2$. This means that from that point on, we get $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$, which means that the sequence is monotonically decreasing. At the same time, it is trivial that $x_n>0$ for all $n$. Thus $x_n$ must converge.

Comment: That's what the OP calls "ratio test". Too hard.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You sure? Because that's not what I call "ratio test". That would be testing the ratio between $x_{n+1}-x_n$ and $x_{n}-x_{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure. But given that the ratio test is meant not for sequences, but for series, it's my best guess what the OP thinks it means.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=\sqrt[200]2-1$ and note that $h>0$.
Then using Bernoulli's inequality
$$ 2^n=(2^{n/200})^{200}=((1+h)^n)^{200}\ge (1+hn)^{200}>h^{200}n^{200}$$
so that
$$0<\frac{n^{100}}{2^n}<\frac{1}{h^{200}n^{100}}<\epsilon $$
as soon as $n>{\frac1{h^2\sqrt[100]\epsilon}}$.

Comment: Isn't Bernoulli's inequality equivalent to  "exponentials grow faster than polynomials"?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter It is the statement that one certain linear polynomial grows slower than one particular exponential function. So it's not quite that general. At least on the face of it.

Answer (score 0):

As an elementary method, note that for $n>10$, we have $n+1< 1.1n$ hence the numerator of $x_n$ increases at a rate of at most $1.1$ and the denominator increases at a rate of exactly $2$, a sufficient condition for $x_n\to0$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{n^{100}}{2^n} =2^{100} \frac{n^{100}}{2^{n+100}}$$
Now $$2^{n+100}> \binom{n+100}{101} = \frac{(n+100)(n+99) \cdots (n+1)n}{101 !}> \frac{n^{101}}{101!}$$

Therefore
$$\frac{n^{100}}{2^n} < 2^{100}\cdot  101! \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: $\sum \frac1n = \infty$

Comment: it doesn't help prove convergence of the series.